# GQL query with numeric id in datastore viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I want to build GQL query to get an object using its numeric id. I'm doing this in Datastore viewer in App management console, so I can't use Model.get_by_id(numeric_id). Something like

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE id = <numeric_id>
```

also doesn't work.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Model where __key__ = KEY('Model', <numeric_id>)
```

Comment: GQL! How can you not love it. /irony

Comment: That does a full match on the key rather than just the ID part of the key. I'd like to get all the entities with the given numeric id, not just the one with no parent.

Comment: When I run it in dataviewer it's working, but in the code i get:',' expected at character 34 in "__key__ = KEY('DataviewUserData' , 6227633859723264)"

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to write a query equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE id = <numeric_id>
```

which would select all Model entities with the given id. If you're ok with something equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE id = <numeric_id> AND parent IS NULL
```

you can use something like

```
SELECT * FROM Model where __key__ = KEY('Model', <numeric_id>)
```

If your entity does have a parent though, you'll need to specify that as part of the key, like

```
SELECT * FROM Model where __key__ = KEY('ParentModel', <parent_name_or_id>, 'Model', <numeric_id>)
```

If the parent itself has a parent, you'll need to specify that too. (Grandparent goes left of the parent, and so on.)

Of course if you're not restricted to GQL (like if you're using Python, Go, or Java), you can query the keys, decode them and filter by id, then fetch the corresponding entities. But of course that doesn't work in the Datastore Viewer since you can only use GQL.

Answer (score 2):

Another way around is, first get the key for the entity using the id by

```
key = db.Key.from_path('Model', int(id))
```

then get the object by

```
obj = db.get(key)
```

The advantage is, you do not have to do any string formatting.

reference: problem set 3 at this course, https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs253/

Comment: You should remove the '.' after `from_path` that is a syntax error. It works otherwise though

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error:

> GQL Query error: Encountered ... at line 1, column 42. Was expecting
>   one of: UNQUOTED_NAME ... QUOTED_NAME ..."

It turns out that in the Google AppEngine datastore developer's admin console, you should drop the quotes and use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE __key__ = Key(MyEntity, 5695872079757312)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to change the type of ID from String to Long