# GQL query checking numerical id within a list of ids

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I'm trying to compare the unique numerical id of an element in my database with a list of longs.

My GQL query should return those elements which have this id I'm passing as part of their array of longs.

I've tried using a statement of the form:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN :1", list_of_stored_ids
```

I've also tried using this question: [GQL query with numeric id in datastore viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869858/gql-query-with-numeric-id-in-datastore-viewer), but I still can't find any way to compare to a list.

Is there such a way? If not, what must I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build up a list of ndb keys, not numeric ids, in order to get this to work.

eg:

```
ids = [5918782761467904, 5624113645223936, 5463928544952320]
keys = [ndb.Key('<Entity>', id) for id in ids]
entities = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM <Entity> WHERE __key__ IN :1", keys).fetch()
```

or (non-GQL version)

```
entities = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```